# Locate and hide item in list containing the word "Ice"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jquery-ui

The question that the teacher had assigned is as follows:

Have a radio  button in which you use a filter to hide all items that have the word “Ice” in them (e.g. “Ice Cream” and “Iced Tea”)

This is the current code that I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Assignment 02</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function hideParagraph()
      {
        $('#drinks_div').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#desserts_div').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#drinks_div').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#desserts_div').fadeIn(1000);
      }

    function hideAboutAndThings()
      {
        $('#about_me').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#things_I_like').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#about_me').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#things_I_like').fadeIn(1000);
      }
    

    function hideFirstItemDrinks()
      {
        $("li:first").hide();
      }

    function hideFirstItemDesserts()
      {
        $("#listTwo li:first").hide();
      }

    function hideWordsWithIce()
      {
        $("#drinks_div[li*='ice']").hide();
      }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1> My First jQuery Page</h1>

    <div id="about_me">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    Born in the suburbs of Chicago, I've always been here my whole life. I am fascinated by the city during the night, the lights create great photographs. 
    </div> <!--this is the end of the div for about me -->

    <div id="things_I_like">
    <h2>Things I like </h2>
    I am a photographer so I enjoy taking pictures, often times when I am finished with work at my job I will go to the gym to work out and let off some steam. 
    </div> <!--this is the end of the div for things I like -->

    <div id="drinks_div">
    <h2> Drinks</h2>
    <p>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none" id="listOne">
          <li>1. Tea</li>
          <li>2. Water</li>
          <li>3. Kombucha</li>
          <li>4. Iced Coffee </li>
        </ul>
    <p>
    </div> <!--this is the end of the div for drinks -->

    <div id="desserts_div">
    <h2> Desserts</h2>
      <ul style="list-style-type:none" id="listTwo">
          <li>1. Portillo's Choclate Cake</li>
          <li>2. Tiramisu</li>
          <li>3. Mint Chocolate Chip Ice Cream</li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!--this is the end of the div for desserts -->
    <div id="change_items">
      <form action="">
      <p>Fade H2s inside Food<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Fade H2s inside Food" onclick="hideParagraph()"></p>
      
      <p>Fade the 'About Me' H2s<input type="radio" name="option_item"value="Fade the 'About Me' H2s" onclick="hideAboutAndThings()"></p>
      
      <p>Hide first item under drinks<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Hide first item under drinks' H2s" onclick="hideFirstItemDrinks()"></p>
      
      <p>Hide first item under desserts<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Hide first item under desserts' H2s" onclick="hideFirstItemDesserts()"></p>
       
      <p>Hide all items with the word 'Ice' in them<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Hide all items with the word 'Ice' in them " onclick="hideWordsWithIce()"> </p>
       
      <p>Make all list items visible<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Make all list items visible" onclick="hideParagraph()"></p>
     </form>
    </div> <!--this is the end of the div for change items -->
</body>

</html>
```

The only issue I'm having is that I don't know what the exact function is and how to write it. If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. For something like this, you can use the [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to target elements where the text appears directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof.

```js
function hideParagraph() {
  $('#drinks_div').fadeOut(1000);
  $('#desserts_div').fadeOut(1000);
  $('#drinks_div').fadeIn(1000);
  $('#desserts_div').fadeIn(1000);
}

function hideAboutAndThings() {
  $('#about_me').fadeOut(1000);
  $('#things_I_like').fadeOut(1000);
  $('#about_me').fadeIn(1000);
  $('#things_I_like').fadeIn(1000);
}

function hideFirstItemDrinks() {
  $("li:first").hide();
}

function hideFirstItemDesserts() {
  $("#listTwo li:first").hide();
}

function hideWordsWithIce() {
  var $items = $("#listOne, #listTwo").find("li:contains('Ice')");
  $.each($items, function(i, item) {
    $(this).hide();
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="about_me">
  <h2>About Me</h2>
  Born in the suburbs of Chicago, I've always been here my whole life. I am fascinated by the city during the night, the lights create great photographs.
</div>
<!--this is the end of the div for about me -->

<div id="things_I_like">
  <h2>Things I like </h2>
  I am a photographer so I enjoy taking pictures, often times when I am finished with work at my job I will go to the gym to work out and let off some steam.
</div>
<!--this is the end of the div for things I like -->

<div id="drinks_div">
  <h2> Drinks</h2>
  <p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none" id="listOne">
      <li>1. Tea</li>
      <li>2. Water</li>
      <li>3. Kombucha</li>
      <li>4. Iced Coffee </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
</div>
<!--this is the end of the div for drinks -->

<div id="desserts_div">
  <h2> Desserts</h2>
  <ul style="list-style-type:none" id="listTwo">
    <li>1. Portillo's Choclate Cake</li>
    <li>2. Tiramisu</li>
    <li>3. Mint Chocolate Chip Ice Cream</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--this is the end of the div for desserts -->
<div id="change_items">
  <form action="">
    <p>Fade H2s inside Food<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Fade H2s inside Food" onclick="hideParagraph()"></p>

    <p>Fade the 'About Me' H2s<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Fade the 'About Me' H2s" onclick="hideAboutAndThings()"></p>

    <p>Hide first item under drinks<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Hide first item under drinks' H2s" onclick="hideFirstItemDrinks()"></p>

    <p>Hide first item under desserts<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Hide first item under desserts' H2s" onclick="hideFirstItemDesserts()"></p>

    <p>Hide all items with the word 'Ice' in them<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Hide all items with the word 'Ice' in them " onclick="hideWordsWithIce()"> </p>

    <p>Make all list items visible<input type="radio" name="option_item" value="Make all list items visible" onclick="hideParagraph()"></p>
  </form>
</div>
<!--this is the end of the div for change items -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next code and tellme if it works:

```
function hideWordsWithIce()
{
    $("li:contains('Ice')").hide();
}
```